# Xlib ARGB Window Icon

Tags: xlib, window-managers

I have a ARGB image data. I wish to set my window icon to this data. After searching for hours I am still at the start with nothing at hand. I know that I need to create a pixmap for image data and (may be) another pixmap for mask and use hints to hint the window manager about this. However, I do not know how to setup 32bit ARGB or 24bit RGB + 8bit alpha image. A sample would really be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 32 bit depth visual is available (check xdpyinfo) then code from [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492275/how-to-upload-32-bit-image-to-server-side-pixmap) should work for you. After you create RGBA pixmap just assign it's handle to [_NET_WM_ICON](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2578661) property

Comment: Thanks alot, I will look into it. Can I count on most modern X implementations on modernish hardware (after 2005) will have this support?

Comment: I guess I will need a bit more help, I have successfully created pixmap however, I have no idea how to set _NET_WM_ICON property. I have tried setting WM_HINTS but didnt worked.

Comment: Ok, did it with this sample and _NET_WM_ICON property: http://lists.kde.org/?l=kwin&m=115435217715650&w=2

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled upon this thread after quite some investigation on the topic, and I wasn't even able to get example code working on my system.

Turns out the buffer needs to be `long` and *not* `int` on 64 bit systems.

Corrected exampled below

```c
/* gcc -Wall -Wextra -Og -lX11 -lstdc++ -L/usr/X11/lib -o native foo.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    unsigned long buffer[] = {
            16, 16,
            4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 338034905, 3657433343, 0, 184483840, 234881279, 3053453567, 3221225727, 1879048447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1224737023, 3305111807, 3875537151,0, 0, 2063597823, 1291845887, 0, 67109119, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 50266112, 3422552319, 0, 0, 3070230783, 2063597823, 2986344703, 771752191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3422552319, 0, 0, 3372220671, 1509949695, 704643327, 3355443455, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 3422552319, 0, 134152192, 3187671295, 251658495, 0, 3439329535, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3422552319, 0, 0, 2332033279, 1342177535, 167772415, 3338666239, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 3422552319, 0, 0, 436207871, 3322085628, 3456106751, 1375731967, 4278255360, 4026597120, 3758161664, 3489726208, 3204513536, 2952855296, 2684419840, 2399207168, 2130771712, 1845559040, 1593900800, 1308688128, 1040252672, 755040000, 486604544, 234946304, 4278255360, 4043374336, 3774938880, 3506503424, 3221290752, 2952855296, 2667642624, 2399207168, 2130771712, 1862336256, 1627453957, 1359017481, 1073805064, 788591627, 503379721, 218169088, 4278255360, 4043374336, 3758161664, 3506503424, 3221290752, 2952855296, 2684419840, 2415984384, 2130771712, 1862336256, 1577123584, 1308688128, 1040252672, 755040000, 486604544, 218169088, 4278190335, 4026532095, 3758096639, 3489661183, 3221225727, 2952790271, 2667577599, 2415919359, 2130706687, 1862271231, 1593835775, 1325400319, 1056964863, 771752191, 520093951, 234881279, 4278190335, 4026532095, 3758096639, 3489661183, 3221225727, 2952790271, 2667577599, 2415919359, 2130706687, 1862271231, 1593835775, 1325400319, 1056964863, 771752191, 503316735, 234881279, 4278190335, 4026532095, 3758096639, 3489661183, 3221225727, 2952790271, 2684354815, 2399142143, 2130706687, 1862271231, 1593835775, 1325400319, 1040187647, 771752191, 520093951, 234881279, 4294901760, 4043243520, 3774808064, 3506372608, 3221159936, 2952724480, 2684289024, 2399076352, 2147418112, 1862205440, 1593769984, 1308557312, 1040121856, 771686400, 503250944, 234815488, 4294901760, 4060020736, 3758030848, 3506372608, 3221159936, 2952724480, 2684289024, 2415853568, 2130640896, 1862205440, 1593769984, 1308557312, 1040121856, 771686400, 503250944, 234815488, 4294901760, 4043243520, 3774808064, 3489595392, 3237937152, 2952724480, 2684289024, 2415853568, 2147418112, 1862205440, 1593769984, 1325334528, 1056899072, 788463616, 503250944, 234815488,
            32, 32,
            4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 268369920, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 1509949695, 3120562431, 4009754879, 4194304255, 3690987775, 2130706687, 83886335, 0, 50331903, 1694499071, 3170894079, 3992977663, 4211081471, 3657433343, 1879048447, 16777471, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3087007999, 2281701631, 1191182591, 1040187647, 2030043391, 4127195391, 2566914303, 0, 16777471, 3254780159, 2181038335, 1191182591, 973078783, 2030043391,4177527039, 2130706687, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2214592767, 4093640959, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2298478847, 3909091583, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2214592767, 3607101695, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1946157311, 4093640959, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 536871167, 1191182591, 2281701631,3019899135, 637534463, 0, 0, 0, 100597760, 251592704, 33488896, 0, 3321889023, 2919235839, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2550137087, 4278190335, 4278190335, 3405775103, 570425599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2046820607, 4043309311, 620757247, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 33488896, 0, 0, 218104063, 1291845887, 3841982719, 3388997887, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1996488959, 4093640959, 1073742079, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1761607935, 4278190335, 150995199, 0, 0, 67109119, 2550137087, 3909091583, 889192703, 0, 0, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2181038335, 3925868799, 0, 0, 218104063, 3070230783, 3623878911, 570425599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 805306623, 3288334591, 1795162367, 1040187647, 1023410431, 2231369983, 4211081471, 1694499071, 0, 369099007, 3456106751, 3825205503, 1174405375, 872415487, 872415487, 872415487, 872415487, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4293984270, 2046951677, 3422552319, 4110418175, 4177527039, 3405775103, 1409286399, 0, 0, 1409286399, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760,4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3875602176, 3741384448, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3053518592, 2936078080, 2801860352, 2650865408, 2516647680, 2382429952, 2264989440, 2113994496, 1996553984, 1862336256, 1728118528, 1577123584, 1459683072, 1325465344, 1191247616, 1040252672, 922812160, 771817216, 637599488, 503381760, 385941248, 234946304, 100728576, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3875602176, 3724607232, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3070295808, 2936078080, 2801860352, 2667642624, 2516647680, 2399207168, 2264989440, 2130771712, 1996553984, 1845559040, 1728118528, 1593900800, 1459683072, 1308688128, 1191247616, 1057029888, 922812160, 788594432, 637599488, 503381760, 369164032, 234946304, 117505792, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3875602176, 3741384448, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3053518592, 2919300864, 2801860352, 2650865408, 2533424896, 2399207168, 2264989440, 2113994496, 1996553984, 1862336256, 1728118528,1593900800, 1459683072, 1325465344, 1191247616, 1040252672, 906034944, 771817216, 654376704, 503381760, 369164032, 234946304, 117505792, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3858824960, 3741384448, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3070295808, 2936078080, 2801860352, 2667642624, 2533424896, 2382429952, 2264989440, 2130771712, 1979776768, 1862336256, 1728118528, 1577123584, 1442905856, 1325465344, 1191247616, 1040252672, 922812160, 771817216, 637599488, 503381760, 369164032, 234946304, 100728576, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3875602176, 3741384448, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3070295808, 2919300864, 2801860352, 2667642624, 2533424896, 2399207168, 2264989440, 2113994496, 1996553984, 1862336256, 1728118528, 1593900800, 1442905856, 1342241795, 1174470400, 1057029888, 906034944, 788594432, 654376704, 503381760, 385941248, 251723520, 100728576, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3741319423, 3623878911, 3472883967, 3338666239, 3221225727, 3070230783, 2952790271, 2818572543, 2667577599, 2533359871, 2399142143, 2264924415, 2147483903, 1996488959, 1862271231, 1728053503, 1593835775, 1459618047, 1325400319, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 520093951,385876223, 251658495, 117440767, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3741319423, 3623878911, 3489661183, 3355443455, 3221225727, 3087007999, 2936013055, 2801795327, 2667577599, 2533359871, 2399142143, 2281701631, 2130706687, 1996488959, 1862271231, 1728053503, 1593835775,1459618047, 1325400319, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 520093951, 385876223, 234881279, 100663551, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3758096639, 3623878911, 3489661183, 3355443455, 3221225727, 3087007999, 2936013055, 2801795327, 2667577599, 2550137087, 2415919359, 2264924415, 2130706687, 1996488959, 1862271231, 1728053503, 1593835775, 1459618047, 1325400319, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 503316735, 369099007, 251658495, 100663551, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3758096639, 3623878911, 3489661183, 3355443455, 3204448511, 3087007999, 2936013055, 2818572543, 2667577599, 2533359871, 2399142143, 2264924415, 2130706687, 1996488959, 1879048447, 1728053503, 1593835775, 1459618047, 1325400319, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 520093951, 385876223, 251658495, 117440767, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3758096639, 3623878911, 3489661183, 3355443455, 3221225727, 3087007999, 2952790271, 2818572543, 2667577599, 2533359871, 2399142143, 2264924415, 2147483903, 2013266175, 1862271231, 1744830719, 1610612991, 1476395263, 1342177535, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 520093951, 385876223, 251658495, 100663551, 4294901760, 4160684032, 4026466304, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3623813120, 3489595392, 3355377664, 3237937152, 3103719424, 2952724480, 2818506752, 2684289024, 2550071296, 2415853568, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2013200384, 1878982656, 1744764928, 1593769984, 1476329472,1325334528, 1207894016, 1056899072, 939458560, 788463616, 654245888, 520028160, 385810432, 251592704, 117374976, 4294901760, 4177461248, 4043243520, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3640590336, 3506372608, 3355377664, 3221159936, 3086942208, 2952724480, 2818506752, 2701066240, 2550071296, 2415853568, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2013200384, 1878982656, 1727987712, 1610547200, 1476329472, 1325334528, 1191116800, 1073676288, 922681344, 788463616, 654245888, 520028160, 385810432, 251592704, 100597760, 4294901760, 4177461248, 4043243520, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3640590336, 3489595392, 3372154880, 3237937152, 3103719424, 2952724480, 2818506752, 2700935170, 2550071296, 2415853568, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2013200384, 1878982656, 1744764928, 1610547200, 1459552256, 1342111744, 1191116800, 1056899072, 922681344, 788463616, 671023104, 520028160, 385810432, 251592704, 100597760, 4294901760, 4177461248, 4043243520, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3640590336, 3489595392, 3372154880, 3237937152, 3086942208, 2969501696, 2818506752, 2684289024, 2550071296, 2432630784, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2013200384, 1862205440, 1744764928, 1610547200, 1476329472, 1342111744, 1191116800, 1056899072, 922681344, 788463616, 654245888, 520028160, 385810432, 251592704, 117374976, 4294901760, 4177461248, 4043243520, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3623813120, 3506372608, 3372154880, 3237937152, 3103719424, 2952724480, 2835283968, 2684289024, 2550071296, 2432630784, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2046492676, 1862205440, 1744764928, 1610547200, 1476329472, 1342111744,1207894016, 1056899072, 939458560, 788463616, 654245888, 536281096, 385810432, 251592704, 134152192,
    };
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(0);
    int s = DefaultScreen(d);
    Atom net_wm_icon = XInternAtom(d, "_NET_WM_ICON", False);
    Atom cardinal = XInternAtom(d, "CARDINAL", False);
    Window w;
    XEvent e; w = XCreateWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 0, 0, 200, 200, 0,
    CopyFromParent, InputOutput, CopyFromParent, 0, 0);
    int length = 2 + 16 * 16 + 2 + 32 * 32;
    XChangeProperty(d, w, net_wm_icon, cardinal, 32, PropModeReplace, (const unsigned char*) buffer, length);
    XMapWindow(d, w);
    while(1)
    XNextEvent(d, &e);
    (void)argc, (void)argv;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I didn't checked it on 64bit systems, but it will cause issues porting.

Comment: Thanks for this, your answer brought an end to an hour or so of head scratching.

Comment: This cost me a good hour in debugging. Everything points to Cardinal being 32bit, while the client buffer being in 64bit. The spec doesn't help either (even though it has been [discussed](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2009-January/010171.html)) :(