# How to load XPM into XWMHints icon_pixmap property?

Tags: icons, x11

Is there a simple ready solution to just `#include <icon.xpm>` and get it as your app icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example code answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699927/xlib-argb-window-icon/10714086#10714086) - you need to upload rgba data to server-side pixmap and assign [_NET_WM_ICON](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2578661) value to pixmap id.

Unfortunately this won't work for ubuntu/unity - there you set icon in the desktop file and associate your window with desktop file using [by setting _NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE property](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530376/association-window-desktop-file-launcher-entry/530431#530431) ( see my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007528/retrieve-ubuntu-launcher-icon/33018943#33018943) )