# X11 - XCreateImage, Visual * vis parameter

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib

I'm working with X11 and I've been looking for the reason why, in every program I've seen trying to create an image with XCreateImage, the parameter vis is set to "CopyFromParent".

I've already see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492275/how-to-upload-32-bit-image-to-server-side-pixmap) in stackoverflow.

But the examples also use the same value.
¿Could anyone explain me the reason?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's one of Xlib's classes which says "copy the Visual class Type from the parent". Visual Type being "DirectColor", "PsuedoColor", "red_mask", "green_mask", "blue_mask", etc.

http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/visual-types.html#Visual

`CopyFromParent` is a flag saying "copy these values from the, typically the main display window - `XOpenDisplay(NULL)`.

Comment: I knew the meaning of CopyFromParent. What I don't know are the exact values.

Comment: `X11/X.h` says `#define CopyFromParent  0L` and `X11/Xlib.h` says `typedef struct { XExtData *ext_data; VisualID visualid; int class; unsigned long red_mask, green_mask, blue_mask;  int bits_per_rgb; int map_entries; } Visual;`  If you want to get the actual values before your create the image, try calling `XGetVisualInfo`